# Getting Error when using mergeMap to merge two sequential subscriptions in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I have two sequential subscriptions:

```
 this.authService.tokenObs.pipe( map(res => res),mergeMap( token =>
    this.service.getUsers(token).subscribe(res2=>{
            console.log('res2', res2)
  })
));
```

I get error on token param within merge map:

> Argument of type '(token: {}) => Subscription' is not assignable to
>
> parameter of type '(value: {}, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
>
> Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
>
> Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
>
> Property 'length' is missing in type 'Subscription'. (parameter) token: {}

I am using mergeMap for first time so not familiar with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code like below

```
this.authService.tokenObs.pipe(
     map(res => res),
     mergeMap(this.service.getUsers(token))
).subscribe(res2=>{
    console.log('res2', res2)
});
```

---

Since you are new to this, Can you take a look at the working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsefpz

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').pipe(
      map(res => res[0].id),
      mergeMap(id => this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${id}`))
    ).subscribe(res2 => {
      console.log('res2', res2)
    });
  }
}
```

---

EDIT 2:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsefpz

Updated the code for handling error. Test the error case you changing it to wrong url.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { map, mergeMap, tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('data >>> ', data)),
      map(res => res[0].id),
      tap(data => console.log('transformed data >>> ', data)),
      mergeMap(id => this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${id}`)),
      catchError(error => {
        console.log('ERROR >>>> ', JSON.stringify(error));
        return throwError({ status: error.status, errorMsg: error.statusText });
      })
    ).subscribe(res2 => { console.log('res2', res2) }, err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT 3**
for rxjs 5.5
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-tutorial-yzowvt

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .do(data => console.log('data >>> ', data))
    .map(res => res[0].id)
    .do(data => console.log('transformed data >>> ', data))
    .mergeMap(id => this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${id}`))
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR >>>> ', JSON.stringify(error));
        return Observable.throw({ status: error.status, errorMsg: error.statusText });
    })
    .subscribe(res2 => { console.log('res2', res2) }, err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vivek :). I will check the example and implement the solution. Can you tell me that how can handle error in case this.authService.tokenObs returns error?

Comment: you can use `catchError()` and `throwError` operators

Comment: Vivek, will this work for rxjs 5.5.6?
Because I am getting error for second subscription "TypeError: scheduler.schedule is not a function" and I have replace throwError with  return ErrorObservable.create('error', errorSso); as I could not import throwError. from rxjs package.

Comment: No, it is for rxjs 6

Comment: `throwError `shouldb be `Observable.throw()` in rxjs 5

Comment: @Simer Please try the `EDIT 3`

Comment: Thanks, I will try and accept answer. thanks for your time Vivek Kumar :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want use sequence of Observables depends on each other probably you better use "switchMap":

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.authService.tokenObs.pipe(
   switchMap((token) => {
      return this.service.getUsers(token);
   }),
   map((user) => {
      // do what you want;
   })
)
```

Also you can use "mergeMap":

```
import { mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

this.authService.tokenObs.pipe(
   mergeMap((token) => {
      return this.service.getUsers(token);
   }),
   map((user) => {
      // do what you want;
   })
)
```

The difference is that if this.authService.tokenObs changes, the "switchMap" will cancel the pending request to the server (this.service.getUsers(token)). But "mergeMap" will not cancel, but continue its execution. 
P.S: Try research and start use @ngrx-store for better architecture of system with Observables: https://github.com/ngrx/platform

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy Ivanko for help. Can you please modify the code so that error can be handled. I am trying to understand this solution so not able to modify it right now. Thanks again for help.